# Выборка данных из списка

Tags: python, list

Здравствуйте. Как можно получить лишь имена из такого списка:

```
xlist = [
    ("Jo", 40, 220),
    ("Sue", 40, 240),
    ("Mark", 41, 200), 
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например, так:

```
names = [value[0] for value in xlist]
```

Если список не требуется и достаточно генератора, можно использовать генераторное выражение:

```
names = (value[0] for value in xlist)
```

в этом случае переменная `names` будет доступна для итерирования только один раз, в отличие от первого случая.

Answer (score 5):

Или так:

```
names = map(lambda item: item[0], xlist)
```

Или как показал @soon:

```
from operator import itemgetter
names = map(itemgetter(0), xlist)
```

Comment: А еще лучше - [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: @soon спасибо, обновил ответ

Comment: Не стоит усложнять.
Лямбда (генератор функции) здесь перебор, потому лучше не генерировать функцию там, где можно этого не делать.
itemgetter здесь - перебор, потому что список в задаче не вложенный. Свёртывание списка - оптимальный вариант.

Comment: @idlesign: `lambda` перебор, а вот `itemgetter` в самый раз (не понятно, при чём здесь вложенный не вложенный).

Comment: @jfs Речь о случаях, когда можно единожды создать itemgetter и использовать его рекурсивно применяя к результату. Здесь этого не требуется. Здесь также не требуется другая возможность этой функции, из-за которой её очень удобно использовать - возврат кортежей. Собственно вызов map и itemgetter уже проигрывает в читаемости свёртываниям (comprehensions), и, пусть и на йоту, но проигрывает в скорости исполнения.